# MySQL Query from hell

Tags: mysql

Given the following table info:

```
A       B           C           D       E

1       786788      123.45      0       617
2       786788      654.21      0       3271
3       786788      111.11      0       556
4       786788      224.45      0       1122
5       786788      0.12        12      0   
6       786788      3.21        321     0   
7       786788      0.22        22      0   
8       786788      0.33        33      0   
9       786788      757.57      0       3788
10      786788      545.41      0       2727
11      786788      0.07        7       0   
12      786788      0.05        5       0   
13      786790      50          0       125 
14      786790      50          0       125 
15      786790      50          0       125 
16      786790      50          0       125 
17      786790      50          0       125 
18      786788      1.23        0       6   
19      786788      0.12        0       1   
20      786788      0.12        0       1   
21      786788      0.05        0       0   
22      786788      0.55        0       3   
23      786788      0.45        45      0   
24      786788      1.47        0       7   
25      786788      0.41        0       2   
26      786788      0.74        74      0   
27      786788      100         0       500 
36      786788      5           0       25  
37      786788      24          0       120 
38      786788      23          0       115 
39      786788      1.47        0       7   
40      786788      12          0       60  
41      786788      14          0       70  
43      786222      7.8         0       39  
44      786222      0.12        12      0   
45      786788      47.47       0       237 
46      786788      9.89        989     0   
47      786788      1.23        0       6   
48      786788      1.23        0       6
```

I'm trying to get the following info in one query:

1. DISTINCT(column B)
2. COUNT(DISTINCT(column B))
3. SUM(column C) WHERE column E != 0
4. SUM(column D)
5. SUM(column E)

If all goes well, the result should look like this example (I didn't "SUM" everything for the example):

```
786788      32      SUM(column C) WHERE column E != 0       SUM(column D)       SUM(column E)
786790      5       SUM(column C) WHERE column E != 0       SUM(column D)       SUM(column E)
786222      2       SUM(column C) WHERE column E != 0       SUM(column D)       SUM(column E)
```

Comment: And your attempted query so far is?

Comment: and how will the results be formatted? `DISTINCT(column B)` returns multiple rows while `count` AND `sum` return only one row

Comment: @InSane I've tried many variations, you'll just have to take my word on that. I'm here to learn from the answers, not to copy and paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, your proposed field-list is pretty close to what you'd actually need in a query. I haven't tested this, but give this one a shot (it uses MySQL's `GROUP BY` to do the `DISTINCT`/grouping you require):

```
SELECT
    B,
    COUNT(*),
    SUM((CASE WHEN E != 0 THEN C ELSE 0 END)),
    SUM(D),
    SUM(E)

FROM
    your_table

GROUP BY B
```

Comment: Ahh, "CASE".. How could I forget CASE? Been too long.

Comment: @rideTheWave Yeah, I love it and hate it =P. Similarly, an `IF()` statement would work just-the-same (as in Larry's answer), if you're not on speaking terms with `CASE` at the present time.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me if you want the SUMs *within* each value of B or across the whole table and repeated on each line.  If the former (which makes the most sense to me), I think this is pretty much what you want:

```
 SELECT B, COUNT(*), SUM(IF(E = 0, 0, C)), SUM(D), SUM(E) 
    FROM FollowingTable GROUP BY B
```

Answer (score 0):

is this work?

```
select b, count(b),sum(case e when 0 then 0 else c end), sum(d), sum(e) from test01 group by b
```